# System.Threading.Thread.Sleep - Display an image for a few seconds and then redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wish to redirect from default.aspx to go.aspx when a button is clicked on. I then require the go.aspx to display an image for a few seconds before redirecting back to the default.aspx. I have tried this...

On the default.aspx I have this VB code:

```
Protected Sub go_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Session("Location") = ddlDestination.SelectedValue
    Response.Redirect("~/go.aspx")
End Sub
```

On the destination page (go.aspx) try to display this image:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/compass.gif" />
```

And have this VB code:

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000)
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx") 
End Sub
```

However, it seems to pause as it should when the button is clicked but then just redirects to the original page. It never displays the image required or go.aspx in any way.

I have also tried putting the code in

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

But still no luck. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using javascript for this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "http://localhost/";
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I'm just learning and never used javascript before. How and where would I add that please?

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this further on Stack Overflow and found this which did the trick..

<script type="text/JavaScript">
      setTimeout("location.href = 'https://www.poolmatchup.com/snookermanager/travel.aspx';",4000);
</script>